# PDO query not returning correctly

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

I cannot get the specific user query to return in the if section (else works fine):

```php
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'name' ] ) ) {
    $person = $_POST[ 'name' ];
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT AVG(ans_1) AS Average FROM responses WHERE email =?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $person);
    $stmt->execute();
} else {
    $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT AVG(ans_1) AS Average FROM responses");
}

$result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
$json = json_encode($result);
echo $json;
```

The php is called by ajax supplying the variable with POST:

```
var user = "ratsnitchbrianthegoodtimeruiner";
$.ajax({
          url: "test.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {name: user},
          dataType: "json",
          success: function (data) {
              alert(data);
}
});
```

I know my ajax script POST variable is working because when I change the dataType to html, and modify the php to just throw in two echo commands like so:

```php
if ( isset( $_POST[ 'name' ] ) ) {
    $person = $_POST[ 'name' ];
    echo $person;
} else {
    echo ("No one set");
}
```

The alert(data) prompt in success works fine.

So it must be something amiss with my PDO statements in the if?
The else returns the data just fine.

Thanks for any help!

###################################

> Note to whoever merged to this question: [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)
> **It does not relate.**

I am able to get the POST data (username) just fine. (they were not in that question).

I am getting response in json just fine on the else statement (again  an issue in that question that isn't a problem here).

90 minutes later..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using MySQLi syntax to bind the parameter, rather than PDO syntax. It should be:

```
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT AVG(ans_1) AS Average FROM responses WHERE email = :email");
    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $person);
```

Comment: New to PDO, is there any benefit besides line reduction to combine the execute and bind?
$stmt->execute(["email"' , $person]); for ?
$stmt->execute(["email"' => $person]); for :email

Comment: No, they're equivalent. I usually use the combined approach.

Comment: But you have the syntax wrong, it should be `["email" => $person]`